# Related rows ordering when using JOIN without ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have two tables:

```
user:
id,name                             
1,bob
2,alice
```

```
user_group:
id,user_id,group
1,1,g1
2,1,g2
3,2,g2
4,2,g3
```

We don't have guarantees that on each execution of `SELECT * FROM user` without `ORDER BY` result set will have the same order. But what about related rows in joins?

For example,
`SELECT user.name, user_group.group FROM user INNER JOIN user_group ON (user.id = user_group.user_id);`. Will the related(joined) rows be adjacent in the result set(take PostgreSQL for ex.)? By that I imply:

```
bob,g1
bob,g2
alice,g2
alice,g3
```

OR

```
alice,g3
alice,g2
bob,g2
bob,g1
```

and NOT this:

```
bob,g1
alice,g2
bob,g2
alice,g3
```

The order of `user`s doesn't matter, the order of `group`s within each `user` too

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: No. The only way to ensure you get a consistent ordering of rows is by using an ORDER BY. Otherwise, the RDBMS is free to order rows any way it sees fit. Whether the columns happen to be in a JOINed table, a UNIONed table, or any other form, you need an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fundamental rule in SQL that you can never rely on the ordering of a result set unless you add an `ORDER BY`. If you have no `ORDER BY`, the ordering of the result set can, among others, depend on

- the order in which PostgreSQL reads the individual tables – it could be in index order or in sequential order, and even with a sequential scan you don't always get the same order (unless you disable [`synchronize_seqscans`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-SYNCHRONIZE-SEQSCANS))
- the join strategy chosen (nested loop, hash join or merge join)
- the number of rows returned by the query (if you use a cursor, PostgreSQL optimizes the query so that the first rows can be returned quickly)

That said, with your specific example and PostgreSQL as database, I think that all join strategies will not return the result set in the order you describe as undesirable. But I wouldn't rely on that: often, the optimizer finds a surprising way to process a query.

The desire to save yourself an `ORDER BY` often comes from a wish to optimize processing speed. But correctness is more important than speed, and PostgreSQL can often find a way to return the result in the desired order without having to sort explicitly.